# SonarQube edition explanation

Tags: sonarqube

Because we need in my team to use a code quality analyzer ad integrate it on our Jenkins

Can the Community version of SonarQube be used freely in a company for the development of a company software?

Because we saw that there exist a developer/entreprise/data center version, but explanations isn't clear in terms of how a company can use without any payment licence

We have Java code in majority, but also a project in C++, Python, and LUA, but for the moment is only for Java code analyzing

Thank you so much and best regards

Comment: Hello, there is the open-source version here
https://www.sonarsource.com/open-source-editions/

Comment: @Romka useless comment ... I don't need link for open-source edition, just knowing if we can use community edition without any payment

Comment: sorry to have bothered you, I will be careful to not try to help you, in the future.